# "mix ecto.create" creates a database with tables from other database by itself

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

When I'm creating a database by:

```
mix ecto.drop
mix ecto.create
```

it creates a database with a few tables from other database and project. That project isn't even in Elixir and it's in a different folder. Note that I've not run a migration yet.

There's no reference in this project to those tables or database.

How to fix that?

Comment: Is the other database named `template1` or does `template1` contain the same tables that you get created automatically in your brand new database with `mix ecto.create`?

Comment: @Dogbert, that's not template1. it doesn't.

Comment: What if you run `CREATE DATABASE foo;` (where `foo` is a database that doesn't already exist) manually in `psql`? Does the new `foo` database contain the same data?